# Maximum sufficient statistics?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose $\{X_i: i = 1, \ldots, n\}$ follows the parametric family of distribution $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n|\theta)$.  According to Neyman-Fisher Factorization Theorem, if a statistic $T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is such that $f$ can be factorized in the form $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n|\theta)=g\left(\theta, T(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\right) h(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, then $T$ is a sufficient statistic for the family.  Then, is the identity function $T(X_1, \ldots, X_n)=(X_1, \ldots, X_n)$ a sufficient statistic?

Answer (score 0):

The identity statistic is always sufficient for all parameters in the family, because sufficiency relates to *data reduction*.  Tautologically, all the information about the parameters that is contained in the sample, remains in the the sample--that is to say, because no data reduction is achieved, no information is lost.

The notion that a statistic must be a function whose image is a subset of $\mathbb R$ is incorrect.  Statistics need not map to a real number.  A statistic is a function of a sample that does not depend on any unknown parameters.  Last time I checked, functions are not restricted to having $\mathbb R$ as the codomain.  Indeed, if you were to impose such a restriction, then the concept of a sufficient statistic, not to mention minimal sufficient statistics, would not be defined for many parametric distributions, and one would also wonder what we would call realizations of a multinomial random variable or even a bivariate normal random variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and that’s what I believe too and it also follows the Neyman-Fisher Factorization Theorem.  A follow up question, also why I come across this puzzling, is that by Basu Theorem, a sufficient statistic T and an ancillary statistic S are independent.  So if the identity function is a (trivial) sufficient statistic, then S would be independent from the data it is computed from. How could this be possible?

Comment: For your second part, I know T, or any statistics, does not need to be real valued function.  For example it can be a vector valued function, and the parameter $\theta$ can also be high dimensional too.  This question is not about if T has range in real or not.